# Puma output like thin with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

Using thin with rails shows me lots of info in each request ( time, sql request, params... ) in the terminal, when i use puma, all this info is goes only to the log.

There any way of show this info on console?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just follow the instructions [here](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/unicorn/), even though this is for Unicorn/Papertrail.

I put these lines in development.rb

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger.const_get('INFO')
config.log_level    = :info
```

http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/unicorn/

Answer (score -1):

bundle exec rails server  Puma -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000